# Scala: How to convert a protobuf ByteString object to bytes?

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers, scala-java-interop

I have  function that returns a ByteString object:

```
private def getEvent(value: DataOutputValue): com.google.protobuf.ByteString = {
  value.getRecordedEvent.getEvent.getEvent
}
```

How do I get just the bytes from this in Scala?

Answer (score 4):

Call [`toByteArray`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/ByteString#toByteArray--):

```
val bytes = getEvent(someDateOutput).toByteArray
```